# POST data ionic 3 and backend API restful laravel

Tags: rest, ionic-framework, laravel-5, ionic3, ionic-view

I have an issue about POST data at add student page. I'm using ionic 3 and backend API restful laravel, I tried this POST in postman and it's works, but I got an error message "invalid token or token not provided" after click Add button (refer the [first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye6CZ.png) picture). I'm not sure how to write method with auth token.

You can refer my provider ([second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMaxH.png) image) ,addstudent.ts ([third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJk0v.png) image), button html ([forth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52s6q.png) image) for reference

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you stored your token in a storage (e.g localStorage or sessionStorage), you can do the following:

Step1: Add Auth provider and extend BaseRequestOptions

```
import { BaseRequestOptions, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AuthProvider extends BaseRequestOptions {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  }

  merge(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptions {

    let newOptions = super.merge(options);
    let accessToken = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
    if (accessToken !== null && accessToken !== undefined) {
      let token: AcessTokenResponse = JSON.parse(accessToken);
      newOptions.headers.set('Authorization', token.token_type + ' ' + token.access_token);
    }

    return newOptions;
  }
}
```

Step2: Add **AuthProvider** under providers in **app.module.ts** file

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, but i got an error in locationStorage and AccessTokenResponse. It said "[ts] Cannot find name 'locationStorage'." , and "[ts] Cannot find name 'AcessTokenResponse'."

Do i have add any method or class for these ?

Comment: There is a typo it's localStorage, I updated the answer. note that you have to add the code to save 'accessToken' to localStorage first. ideally, when you get the token you will save it as this object (AcessTokenResponse) {token_type: string, access_token: string} where token_type is often 'Bearer'

Answer (score 0):

As per my exprience you need to add `RequestOptions` in your **POST** call like below:

```
    let options = new RequestOptions({
      headers: headers
    });
    this.http.post(this.apiUrl+'/addstudent', addStudent, options)
```

As in your code you are creating Header but not passing it into post request.

Try above code Hope this will help you to get your API work.

Comment: Great ! Please accept this answer if it solve your problem.